# Iterate over rows and append values to column in dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to loop through the rows and transform data shown in pic 1 to that of pic 2.

Having trouble in fetching the corresponding Quarter values as the list I get for each of these colors is not in the sequential order. Can you please suggest how can I attain the result of Pic2?

```
b=[]
r=[]
g=[]
p=[]
for col, col_val in Sample.iteritems():
    for i in col_val.values:
        if 'Blue' in i:
            b.append(i[i.find('(')+1 : i.find('-')])
        elif 'Purple' in i:
            p.append(i[i.find('(')+1 : i.find('-')])
        elif 'Green' in i:
            g.append(i[i.find('(')+1 : i.find('-')])
        elif 'Red' in i:
            r.append(i[i.find('(')+1 : i.find('-')])
```

[image: Pic1]
[image: Pic2]

Comment: Could you get the values, sort them out, and then concatenate to the first column? And can you post the code for your DataFrame so people can test their code to see if it corresponds to your expected result?

Answer (score 0):

The issue got fixed when **iteritems** was replaced by **iterrows**.

```
b=[]
r=[]
g=[]
p=[]
q=[]
for col, col_val in Sample.iterrows():
    for i in col_val.values:
        if 'Blue' in i:
            b.append(pd.to_numeric(i[i.find('(')+1 : i.find('-')]))
        elif 'Purple' in i:
            p.append(pd.to_numeric(i[i.find('(')+1 : i.find('-')]))
        elif 'Green' in i:
            g.append(pd.to_numeric(i[i.find('(')+1 : i.find('-')]))
        elif 'Red' in i:
            r.append(pd.to_numeric(i[i.find('(')+1 : i.find('-')]))
        else:
            q.append(i)
pd.DataFrame(list(zip(q,g,p,r,b))).rename(columns={0:'Quarter',1:'Green',2:'Purple',3:'Red',4:'Blue'})
```

Answer (score 0):

I considered a different approach. I came up with another approach: join the index column and the target column vertically, and then split the column and join it vertically afterwards. I thought it would be easier, but it was fiddly.

```
df.columns = ['Quarter','value','value','value','value']
df1 = pd.DataFrame()
for i in range(1,len(df.columns)):
    df1 = df1.append(df.iloc[:,[0,i]], ignore_index=True)

df2 = pd.concat([df1[['Quarter']], df1['value'].str.split("(", expand=True)], axis=1)
df2 = pd.concat([df2[['Quarter',0]], df2[1].str.split('-', expand=True)], axis=1)

df2.columns = ['Quarter', 'color', 'value', 'tmp']
df2.drop('tmp', inplace=True, axis=1)

final = pd.DataFrame()
for k in df2['Quarter'].unique():
    tmp = df2[df2['Quarter'] == k]
    tmp = tmp.pivot(index='Quarter',columns='color')
    final = final.append(tmp, ignore_index=True)

final = final.droplevel(0, axis=1)
final['Quarter'] = df2['Quarter'].unique()
final = final[['Quarter','Green','Purple','Red','Blue']]

final
color   Quarter Green   Purple  Red Blue
0   Q2  1   6   4   3
1   Q3  6   10  2   7
2   Q4  3   7   6   2
```